# Is Social Engineering off topic.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

Currently there's no other stackexchange site that deals with social engineering and after all we are the site that probably deal most whit it. There is a proposal over at [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5133/social-engineering?referrer=q4Dzn6YpRY5pdZnri3IIJQ2) for a social engineering site but it only have 17 ppl committed to it atm.

My wish is that we accept social engineering questions for now until or if the new site comes up and then move all/ active / new questions there to help it get a smooth start.

My question is what is our opinions on social engineering questions can we talk about it or do we have to wait for the [Aria51 Social Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5133/social-engineering?referrer=q4Dzn6YpRY5pdZnri3IIJQ2) proposal pass?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think social engineering questions are entirely on-topic here - note that our [faq](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) highlights phishing already.  Though of course the other faq restrictions still apply.

Comment: I think it is likely the Social Engineering site is too narrow and may not grow fast enough, in which case we should probably ask to get it merged here. We'll see how it does.

Comment: @rory I can't imagine a world where social engineering would not be absolutely on topic here. It's probably the #1 or #2 way to breach any security at any time.

Comment: @Jeff - yep, that's my thinking. We may then want to change the name from "IT Security" to just "Security"

Comment: @rory not really following why that would require a name change..

Comment: @jeff Some of the Social Engineering topic space is physical security, which has been only lightly dealt with here and is not "IT".  I would love to see it included here also.  It is the perspective and mindset that unites the field IMHO.

Comment: @Jeff Antwood If we change the name from IT to just security the we might be able to merge it whit the [Privacy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31293/privacy?referrer=rmGWZ8VwFFgu6Q_n0IHwNQ2) proposal to. After all it has a lot to do with security to.